# WPF borders and the controls within them

Tags: wpf, xaml, border

This post is about the controls contained within a WPF Border control. It's also about having a border that can appear and disappear without affecting the contained controls.

For the record, I'm using C# and WPF and most of the view stuff is using XAML. I also use MVVM although I'm not sure that's going to be related.

What I had planned for was a border around a control that I could make appear and disappear, for the effect of a highlight or something like that. But when I change certain properties of the Border, for example the Opacity or Visiblity, they impact on the contained controls. I have also tried changing the Background property to Transparent and that has not made a difference.

I do know that some controls have a Border property, but that's not really the case for my situation.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
   <Border BorderThickness="2">
      <YourControl />
   </Border>
   <Border Opacity="0.5" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

This way you can change the opacity of the second border without affecting your control. The trick is that Grid ensures that both elements inside it have the same dimensions.

Also notice how your control is wrapped in another border with the same thickness but with no brush. This is to keep the second border from obscuring your control.

Comment: The first border will wrap around the control and match its size, so that's okay. But will the second one?

Comment: Yes it will. That's what Grid is for here.